# A way to add new tags at pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm working on a project that uses Maven and Eclipse.
In this project I have some artifacts (like jar's, war's and so on) and want to add some features (or 'attributes') to those artifacts. (simple string fields)

Some of these attributes could be something like a "problem-description" tag.
I'm wondering about the possibility of adding these attributes into their own pom.xml associated files.

So, here is my question: there's a way to add customized tags at pom.xml?

If not, could I modify the maven configuration to point to other XML Schema modified by me (to add the validation of the attribute created by me)?

I'm using Maven 3.0.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more information with respect to POM?

Comment: Are you talking about the MANIFEST file ?

Comment: there are only properties in pom.xml to add custom settings. Since the pom.xml follows a xsd schema there is not much space for extensions. Also plugins contains a configuration section where you are free to add custom stuff.

Comment: @wemu, can you write a little example about using 'properties' in pom.xml?

About plugins that you mentioned, do you know any?

Answer (score 9):

you can define properties in pom.xml like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.domain.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.compiler.version>1.6</project.build.compiler.version>
        <myProperty>myValue</myProperty>
    </properties>

</project>
```

so within pom.xml or a filtered file you can use ${myProperty} to have maven fill in "myValue"

if you want to use a plugin this guide may help: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html - within the configuration section you can do almost anything.